# How to bound tile layers in Bing Maps AJAX Control, Version 7.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, bing-maps

I have been attempting to overlay tiles from Weather Central onto a Bing map but have been encountering a problem. I am able to call upon a tile and push it onto the map, however, no matter how big the tile is, it puts the tile everywhere on the map. I would like to be able bound it to a specific place but cannot figure out how in 7.0. In 6.3 the specifications seem straightforward : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429629.aspx but not in 7.0. They have an example here: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#TileLayers1 but even using their code it will still put the tiles everywhere.

Here is my code so far:
function GetMap() {

```
          map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), { credentials: "my creds" });
          var tileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({ uriConstructor: 
          'http://datacloud.wxc.com/?type=tile&datatype=forecast&var=Temperature&time=now&bing=023212&vs=0.9&passkey=my_passkey', height: 256, width: 256});
          var tilelayer = new Microsoft.Maps.TileLayer({ mercator: tileSource, opacity: .7 });

           // Push the tile layer to the map
           map.entities.push(tilelayer);
```

}

Where I do the function GetMap() onload.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hardcoding a particular tile quadkey (023212) in your request - you need to replace this with the {quadkey} placeholder to request the appropriate tile image for each location. i.e.:

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), { credentials: "my creds" });
var tileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({ uriConstructor: 
  'http://datacloud.wxc.com/?type=tile&datatype=forecast&var=Temperature&time=now&bing={quadkey}&vs=0.9&passkey=my_passkey', height: 256, width: 256});
var tilelayer = new Microsoft.Maps.TileLayer({ mercator: tileSource, opacity: .7 });

// Push the tile layer to the map
map.entities.push(tilelayer);
```

(untested, since I don't have a passkey to access the service in question)